# Как создать собственные карты под приложение?

Tags: java, android

Как самому создать карты для мобильного приложения?

Comment: Как хотите, можете картинки рисовать и показывать.

Comment: Можно запустить свой спутник на орбиту и отснять местность.

Comment: Если вы задали такой вопрос, то вы не создадите их, без обид)
А если вам нужно использовать (!) карты, то можете использовать апи гугла, яндекса...для работы с картами

Answer (score 4):

Кроме денег ничего не нужно. Векторизация растровых фото/топооснов в масштабе 1:500 стоит приблизительно от 500 руб/га. То есть квадратный км. карты обойдется вам примерно в $1000

Если замахнетесь на всю Расею-Матушку то надо будет выложить ни много ни мало офигеть сколько вечнозеленых, ну там скидка за объем, то/се, в общем без миллиарда можно не подходить.

Comment: Как вы думаете, приложение 2gis используют свои карты или api гигантов?

Comment: @SegreiUlanov Они сами их делают